# What planes are good for both Aerobatics and XC?

Tags: airplane, aerobatics, aircraft-ownership

Aside from Van’s planes, are there any planes capable of both XC and Aerobatics?

Comment: What are you criteria for "capable"? I'd say pretty much every airplane has some capability of both.

Comment: @FredLarson this is true… I’m referring to planes that are “known” to be good for both… e.g. a Van’s RV7/14.

Comment: “Capable” and “good” are both very subjective.  Got any specific criteria you are looking for?  (Max Gs, max range…). Number of seats?  Cost?!

Comment: @MichaelHall I realise this is a very vague question — i suppose if I had to give you numbers, a touring plane capable of pulling +6gs? or vice versa, a plane you can use in competitions but also can be used to fly comfortably for long distance (say 5h endurance at 75% power)

Comment: Aerobatic aircraft (particularly high performance competition aircraft) are typically less stable than other GA aircraft.  Consequently, they take a higher degree of attention for cross country flights.  You could perhaps install an autopilot and servos, but all that weight takes away from aerobatic performance.  In a similar vein, a strict competition aircraft is going to be barebones in terms of avionics -- day VFR only, and nothing that adds extra weight.  In a cross country aircraft, I'm looking for dual controls, all the fancy nav, wx, traffic gizmos, seats in the back for family, etc.

Comment: @RobMcDonald You make a fair point on the weight and avionics. Dave answered about an aerobatic Bonanza which bridges the gap between the two… how i do not know 

Comment: Long EZs & Berkuts fit the bill. (Not much space for baggage though)

Comment: Back in the early 2000's I remember seeing an airplane parked at Sun-N-Fun that fits your bill.  It was a bubble-canopy Skyraider -- with room in the back for plenty of camping gear & as well as the wife and kid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Cessna 152 Aerobat](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/cessna-152-aerobat/nasm_A20070077000) is certified for aerobatics and also has passible XC performance (depending on what you want to optimize). [You can fit two statistically small people and a bag with 100Kts cruise](https://www.planeandpilotmag.com/article/cessna-152-152-aerobat/) which gets you around a bit faster than a car depending on headwinds. Its also a widely produced airframe, easy to get parts and A&P's for.

[There is apparently an aerobatic Bonanza out there](https://www.avweb.com/ownership/aerobatic-cruisers-all-purpose-fun/) which [could be](https://hartzellprop.com/jim-peitz-aerobatics-in-a-beechcraft-bonanza/) a decent candidate but you would need to actually find one.

Bob Hoover made it clear you can fly [some aerobatic maneuvers in a Shrike Commander](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/north-american-rockwell-shrike-commander-500s-robert-bob-hoover/nasm_A20000796000) which is a decent sized twin for getting places.

Comment: Not so sure I'd want to be doing aerobatics in a beat up 50 year old Aerobat lol.